# member access within null pointer of type 'struct structVarable'

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
struct ListNode* addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode* l1, struct ListNode* l2)
{
    struct ListNode *temp1, *temp2, *temp3, *start;
    temp3 = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    temp3->val = 0;
    temp3->next = NULL;

    if (!temp3)
        exit(0);

    temp1 = l1;
    temp2 = l2;
    int val, v1, v2, v3;

    while (temp1 != NULL && temp2 != NULL)
    {
        v1 = temp1->val;
        v2 = temp2->val;
        val = v1 + v2;

        if (val > 9)
        {
            (temp3->val) = (val - 10); //error here
            temp1 = temp1->next;

            (temp1->val) = ((temp1->val) + 1);
        }
        else
            (temp3->val) = val;

        if (start == NULL)
            start = temp3;

        temp3 = temp3->next;
        temp1 = temp1->next;
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }

    while (temp1 != NULL)
    {
        (temp3->val) = (temp1->val);
        if (start == NULL)
            start = temp3;
        temp3 = temp3->next;
        temp1 = temp1->next;


    }

    while (temp2 != NULL)
    {
        (temp3->val) = (temp2->val);
        if (start == NULL)
            start = temp3;
        temp3 = temp3->next;
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }

    return start;
}
```

There's an error in this line of code (line:31 `(temp3->val)=(val-10);`)
I've tried adding these lines of code after allocating memory for `temp3` (`temp3->val=0; temp3->next=NULL;`), but no use.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Your question should contain a [mcve].

Comment: *`if (!temp3) /* ... */`* is too late. You allredy dereference `temp3` in the two lines before that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you forgot to `malloc` new elements for the new list (aka `start`/`temp3`) inside the loops.

Here:

```
temp3 = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
```

you allocate **one** `struct ListNode` but inside for instance this loop:

```
while (temp1 != NULL && temp2 != NULL)
{
    v1 = temp1->val;
    v2 = temp2->val;
    val = v1 + v2;

    if (val > 9)
    {
        (temp3->val) = (val - 10); //error here
        temp1 = temp1->next;

        (temp1->val) = ((temp1->val) + 1);
    }
    else
        (temp3->val) = val;

    if (start == NULL)
        start = temp3;

    temp3 = temp3->next;   // temp3 will become NULL in first iteration
    temp1 = temp1->next;
    temp2 = temp2->next;
}
```

`temp3` will become NULL in the first iteration so the **next time** you do:

```
(temp3->val) = (val - 10);
```

you dereference a NULL pointer and get a crash.

You'll need to `malloc` a new element in each loop. So instead of just doing `temp3 = temp3->next;` you need something like this in the loop:

```
temp3->next = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));   // No need for cast
temp3 = temp3->next;
if (!temp3->) exit(0);
temp3->val = 0;
temp3->next = NULL;
```

(this applies to all your loops)

Also notice that `start` is **uninitialized**. Remember to initialize it to NULL

Also look at this code:

```
        (temp3->val) = (val - 10); //error here
        temp1 = temp1->next;

        (temp1->val) = ((temp1->val) + 1);
```

I think you need to look at the next two lines as well.

```
        (temp3->val) = (val - 10);
        temp1 = temp1->next;               // Here you change temp1

        (temp1->val) = ((temp1->val) + 1); // Here you dereference temp1
```

Now if `temp1` becomes NULL when it's changed, the dereference will cause another crash.

You should do:

```
        (temp3->val) = (val - 10);
        temp1 = temp1->next;

        if (temp1)
        {
            (temp1->val) = ((temp1->val) + 1);
        }
```

Besides that also do this change:

```
temp3 = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));

if (!temp3)   // Put the check here
    exit(0);

temp3->val = 0;
temp3->next = NULL;

// if (!temp3)  Remove this code
//    exit(0);
```

BTW: You don't need to cast `malloc` Simply do:

```
temp3 = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
```

Comment: Only quibble would be [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) - otherwise, good writeup.